# Why is SSIS option not available in Step Type when scheduling a SQL Server agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am looking to schedule a DTSX package in SQL Server Agent job but SSIS option is not shown in Step Type. Attached the screenshot. SQL Server Version is `SQL Server Developer Ed - 2017 - 14.0.1000.169`

[image: q]

Please guide me on how to enable this option.

-- In 'thoughts'...

Comment: SSIS is an optional component. Is it installed on that SQL Server?

Comment: But on other machines, and for same version of SQL Server,  I didn't specifically install SSIS/SSDT but option appears in the SQL Agent Job Step. Confused now.
Nevertheless, please tell me how to install it. Also, the Import/Export wizard works fine.